# Why int plus float shows me weird number?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I am trying to accomplish my 1st assignment. I don't need a decision but I want to know what am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int chTenders;
    int frOrders;
    int macCh;
    int drinks;
    int sauces;
    float tip;
    float subtotal;
    subtotal = chTenders + frOrders + macCh + drinks + sauces + tip;

    cout << "How many chicken tenders would you like?\n";
    cin >> chTenders;
    cout << "How many orders of fries would you like?\n";
    cin >> frOrders;
    cout << "How many orders of mac and cheese would you like?\n";
    cin >> macCh;
    cout << "How many drinks would you like?\n";
    cin >> drinks;
    cout << "How many sauces would you like?\n";
    cin >> sauces;
    cout << "How much would you like to tip?\n";
    cin >> tip;

    cout << "====Slim's Order====\n";
    cout << "Subtotal $" << subtotal << endl;


    return 0;
        }
```

And when I compile and run this it gives me $2.60929e+08 instead of 6.0:

```
How many chicken tenders would you like?
1
How many orders of fries would you like?
1
How many orders of mac and cheese would you like?
1
How many drinks would you like?
1
How many sauces would you like?
1
How much would you like to tip?
1
====Slim's Order====
Subtotal $2.60929e+08
```

Comment: You add up uninitialized variables, and *then* give them values. Computers are not yet capable of time travel.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik to be fair, this would be perfectly sensible in a datastream language - no time travel necessary. C++ just isn't a datastream language.

Comment: @user3043926 Did you think `subtotal = chTenders + frOrders + macCh + drinks + sauces + tip;` sets up a function?

Not that way. It calculates the values instantly.

Comment: Yeah I see now what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: @user3043926 Never mind :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the order of your calculations is just off. `subtotal` is calculated before you receive input values into the summands (`chTenders`, `frOrders`, etc.). Move the `subtotal=...` line to after the `cin << tip` statement.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the why, you are computing the value of subtotal **before** you assign any values to the variables.  In C++, until you assign a value to a variable, the result of accessing it is based on what ever happened to be written to that bit of memory by some other process.  So you essentially computed a garbage value and then asked the user for input.  It is often considered a good practice in C++ to initialize variables at the same time they are defined.